# Regex for detecting occurrence of word with exception

Tags: php, regex

How can I detect a text before some keywords with exceptions..

Eg. I have this sentence " sugar, egg, milk ,Free of gluten"

And we have this array that contains "gluten, milk", if any of these words occur, warn me.

The result suppose to be only milk because in the example I have free of gluten, that means it does not have gluten.

I need a regex that detect the occurrence of the word except it has "free of" before it or "free" after it.

Edit: 
Here is what I am doing

```
 $pattern = '/\b(' . strtolower($keyword) . ')\b/i'; 

 preg_match($pattern, strtolower($stringToDetect), $matches)
```

Comment: Please post your attempt(s) at constructing such a regular expression, along with the programming language, if relevant.

Comment: I have a regex that detect the occurrence of specific word, but I need to include the "free of" feature

Comment: @palAlaa `Free of gluten,sugar,egg,milk` - It is even free of milk. Technically, the `Free of` applies to all here.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb or something but isn't `"Free of gluten, sugar, egg, milk"` the same as `"Free of gluten, free of sugar, free of egg, free of milk"`? It's the same sentence with comma in between. I understand this is not programming but it's probably vital for the code

Comment: @vivek_23 yes u r totally true, I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex might help:

```
/(?<!free of )\b(?:gluten|milk)\b(?! free)/gi
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnqKwn/1)

Explanation:

The most important bits are the lookbehind at the start and the lookahead at the end. They assert that before `\b(?:gluten|milk)\b`, there must not be `free of`, and after `\b(?:gluten|milk)\b`, there must not be `free`. If there indeed isn't those words, then we match some word boundaries and then either `gluten` or `milk`.

If you have your keywords stored in a variable, you need to separate each keyword with `|` and you need to *escape* them, just in case they contain characters that contain special meaning in regex. One way to escape them is to surround each word (not the whole non-capturing group!) with `\Q` and `\E`.